# cassandra: Exception connecting to localhost/9160. Reason: Connection refused

Tags: cassandra

I am unable to connect to to the cassandra. By this I mean that when I try `cassandra-CLI`, or `pycassaShell` I get the following error:

```
Exception connecting to localhost/9160. Reason: Connection refused.
```

I have tried using a few non-defaul ports but to no joy.

I am running cassandra version 1.0.7

I have tried bounding the service, using restart, stop, start, and force-restart.

Comment: can you `ps -ef|grep cassandra`, and see if server's running? can you paste exact command that you execute on Cassandra-CLI?

Comment: Hi, it is not running...this lead me on a route to see why...turned out tome log files had to be chown'd. Thanks for the hint, it helped! Cassandra is now playing ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was cassandra was not even starting. Solution was to start Cassandra!

Comment: its funny how this answer was downvoted. It was the correct answer. "Connection refused." == "not started" is good to know for Cassandra novices.

Answer (score 2):

Run jps command under root user and kill CassandraDaemon if you will see it. After this you will start Cassandra again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in cassandra, After rename var/lib/cassandra/data to var/lib/cassandra/data1 then cassandra is working fine, If cassandra alloted maximum memory is full then it will throw connection refuse exception